# Convert date with full timezone name to Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, browser, ecmascript-5

I'm processing some data with dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss zz`. For example:

`2019-04-06 08:24:51 Central Daylight Time`

`2018-09-06 12:16:12 Central Standard Time`

`2020-02-14 17:57:33 Central Standard Time`

I want to be able to convert these dates to a Date object in browser JavaScript. However, the Date constructor does not recognize this sort of date format, and moment.js isn't much help (unless I'm missing something).

In practice, I'll probably only ever deal with Central Standard Time and Central Daylight Time, but is there a general solution that would allow me to convert this date format to a Date object?

Comment: Nope, those names aren't really standardized. I have not heard of a library that parses those. Also, asking for library suggestions is one of the reasons for closing questions, specially when you really already have a solution that is viable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Central Standard Time can also be written as CST, you can try

```
new Date('2020-02-14 17:57:33 CST'); // default date output
```

which will give you the full date representation.

Or you could use `Date.parse()` to get the actual timestamp

```
Date.parse('2020-02-14 17:57:33 CST'); // 1581724653000 etc
```

---

Another thought - have you tried [Moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)?

Comment: I'm aware that the abbreviation would give me the right result here, I'm just wondering how to do that when you only have the full length name. I would imagine there's some library or function somewhere that lets me convert from the timezone names to the shortened names.

Comment: @tal The names being passed aren't standard

Comment: @JuanMendes They're how these dates are stored in the resource I'm pulling from. I'd love a way to convert these long-form names to some sort of standardized format I can use with `Date()`, without having some big switch statement or something.

Comment: And @TalKoren, moment.js uses the "Country/Timezone" format (i.e. `America/Chicago` for me), and won't accept the format I'm trying to process.